# Selection sort in descending order - JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, selection

I have a selection sort implemented to sort an array of random integers. I would like the user to choose between ascending or descending order. The ascending sort works flawlessly, although descending does not. Here is what my selection sort looks like:

```
public String selection(int[] array,int num,String order) {
    String output = "";
    int min;
    // This is the descending selection sort
    if (order == "desc") {
        for (int i = num - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            // Assume first element is min
            min = i;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < num; j++) {
                if (array[j] < array[min]) {
                    min = j;

                }
            }
            if (min != i) {
                final int temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[min];
                array[min] = temp;
            }
            output = output + Integer.toString(array[i]) + "\n";
        }
    } // This is the ascending selection sort 
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            // Assume first element is min
            min = i;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < num; j++) {
                if (array[j] < array[min]) {
                    min = j;

                }
            }
            if (min != i) {
                final int temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[min];
                array[min] = temp;
            }
            output = output + Integer.toString(array[i]) + "\n";
        }
    }
    return(output.trim());
}
```

I've seen a few questions similar to mine, although none of the questions I saw had their selection sort set up like this so I was unable to implement their solutions.

Comment: If the min ascending sort works, perhaps use the same loop structure and change the logic to test for max.  It looks like the logic in your descending for loop is incorrect.

Comment: Arrays.sort(array) or Arrays.sort(array, Collections.reverseOrder()); Arrays have a a length, array.length, so don't pass it in.

Comment: It starts with using "==" to compare strings is **wrong**. Use the equals method instead. Then read [mcve] and clearly describe the exact problems. "Isnt working" isnt a working problem description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the `if` blocks should compare to `minPosition` and `maxPosition`, not `i`. Secondly, if you are selecting both `minimum` and `maximum`, then your inner for loop should stop at `a.length - i`, not `a.length` (since the top `i` elements are also sorted). Doing both gives you this as the ascending order algorithm.

```
public static void SortAscending(int[] a){
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
        int maxPosition=i;
        int minPosition=i;
        for(int j = i+1; j < a.length - i; j++){
            if(a[j] < a[minPosition]){
                minPosition = j;
            }
            if(a[j] > a[maxPosition]){
                maxPosition = j;
            }
        }
        /*
        if(i < a.length/2-1)
        */
        swap(a,maxPosition,i);
        swap(a,minPosition,a.length-i-1);
    }
}
```

To switch to descending order, simply add one line.

```
public static void SortDescending(int[] a){
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
        int maxPosition=i;
        int minPosition=i;
        for(int j = i+1; j < a.length - i; j++){
            if(a[j] < a[minPosition]){
                minPosition = j;
            }
            if(a[j] > a[maxPosition]){
                maxPosition = j;
            }
        }
        /*
        if(i < a.length/2-1)
        */
        swap(a,minPosition,maxPosition); // <-- this line
        swap(a,maxPosition,i);
        swap(a,minPosition,a.length-i-1);
    }
}
```

Use `swap` function https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/collections-swap-method-in-java-with-examples/